Anhydrides of -ous oxoacids
Why don't the oxoacids of Nitrogen and Sulphur having a oxidation state less than the maximum (i.e. less than 5 and 6 respectively) form anhydrides?
For example N2O3, which should be nitrous anhydride has a structure with a N-N group joining a nitro (-NO2) and a nitroso group (-NO), similarly in H2S2O5, which should be sulphurous anhydride or disulphurous acid, has a S-S bond which links a sulfonic(-SO3H) and a sulfinic group(-SO2H)

Is there any reason as to why the formation of an anhydride of these species is impossible?
How does this redox reaction result in two similar atoms with different oxidation states (+2 and +4 in N2O3) and (+3 and +5 in H2S2O5) bonded to each other?
What is the mechanism for the formation of these anhydrides and how does it differ from those of the higher oxidation state oxoacids?


@IanBush I am aware that the compound exists, but as the question mentioned, it's not a "true" anhydride of nitrous acid as it doesn't contain a N-O-N bond like pyrophosphoric acid or pyrosulfuric acid or even nitrogen pentoxide (nitric anhydride)

Sulfuric acid anhydride is Sulfur trioxide. 1 less oxygen (sulfurous acid) anhydride is sulfur dioxide. Dinitrogen Trioxide (N2O3) IS the anhydride of nitrous acid. So they do form anhydrides. Nitrous acid in general is unstable
